# Etymology of ’macroule’

Tags: étymologie

One of my favourite birds is the Eurasian coot (fulica atra), in French ”foulque macroule”. Wiktionary suggests without sources that the etymology of macroule is ”diable de mer”. DMF just says macroule meant

> Oiseau de rivière, poule d'eau, foulque

which is circular. So what’s the etymology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D'après le Littré, l'étymologie est inconnue.

Le Larousse indique que cela pourrait provenir du grec macro-oulon (grande gencive), mais je ne vois pas trop le lien (sauf si on considère la tache blanche sur le front qui "agrandit" le bec de l'oiseau.)

Une autre hypothèse, plus probable, est le frison "markot" ou le néerlandais "meerkot/meerkol" qui veulent tous les deux dire "poule d'eau" (ou plutôt poule de lac, car meer=lac). Cette étymologie est à relier avec celle de la macreuse (https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/macreuse) et remonterait au XIVème siècle. (rem: en néerlandais moderne, la poule d'eau (Gallinula chloropus) = waterhoen, la foulque macroule (fulica atra) = meerkoet) )

Diable de mer, à mon humble avis, est plutôt lié aux légendes entourant les macreuses/macroules (oiseau noir = malheur) qu'à une réelle étymologie.

Comment: I'm reminded here of the similar case with the English https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Days_of_Christmas_(song) where each chorus ends on "And a partridge in a pear tree". The etymology of "pear tree" is from "perdrix" which is French for "partridge", so it repeats, "partridge partridge", essentially.